# Looking For A Basic Time/Weather Javascript Widget For My Navbar

Tags: javascript, widget, weather, flipclock

I have a navbar 30px high on my website. I am looking for a basic script to display the current, local Time/Weather for my visitors area.

Looking for a display in a basic text format... something like:

Las Vegas NV 10:35pm 74F

I have found a few online, customizable plug-ins and widgets, but nothing as basic as I am looking for, and nothing that will fit into my 30px high navbar.

If anyone has a working code, please advise. Thanks.

Comment: Jamie, try this. I quickly edited it to show you what's possible: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EmYPZm The code uses http://simpleweatherjs.com/

Comment: Thank you. Looks pretty cool so far. But I see in the code where it ask you to enter a location. I was looking for an option where the data would automatically calculate the visitors location and provide that respective information.

Comment: You're in luck. From their site (simpleweatherjs.com) _"Since geolocation is a common question, it is now supported as of v2.5.0. This means you can use HTML5 geolocation to pass in lat/long to simpleWeather and get data back. See demos below."_

Comment: If you need help let me know.

Comment: Thank you jtrein. I will be looking into this later this evening. If I get stuck, I'll revisit this thread to see if you can help me through it. Thanks again.

Comment: I gave it a shot... not luck. :(

Comment: Check again. I've left instructions in the form of HTML comments inside the "Settings" http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EmYPZm Make sure you put jquery _BEFORE_ `simpleweather.js`

Comment: Remember this requires you create your own HTML (including html, head, body tags), CSS, and JS files copied from the Code Pen example. Should be pretty easy. To test, store everything in a directory on your desktop and open the the HTML file with a web browser.

Comment: I doubt youre onlne now jtrein... but how can I get this code to generate the accurate information respective to a particular site visitors locale automatically?

Comment: http://codepen.io/fleeting/pen/Idsaj Though you need HTTPS connection for it to work. Doesn't look like codepen.io is using it. You probably can get it to work on your computer though (localhost)

Comment: http://simpleweatherjs.com/